# How to add a column of a dictionary of dataframes?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary of 15 dataframes and I was searching around how to add a column to each dataframe based on an operation. In my particular case, I wanted to sum specific columns in each dataframe and have the result of that operation in a new column within each dataframe. Such as below.

`df['Sum'] = df[columnlist].sum(axis=1)`

In order to apply this to each dataframe in the dictionary I ended up with this solution:

```
def sumrows(df):
  df['Sum'] = df[columnlist].sum(axis=1)
  return df
sum = {}
sum = {k: sumrows(v) for k,v in dictionary.items()}
```

I am curious if there is a way to do this with out creating and calling a function within my dictionary comprehension. I didn't see many resources on how to do this so figured this might be a beneficial post for fellow beginners like myself.

Comment: dict comprehension will create a new dictionary with new DataFrames. You could iterate over `dictionary.values` and add columns without creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `df_dict` is your dictionary of dataframes and `columnlist` the list of columns you want to sum over, then you could use [`.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and do:

```
df_sum_dict = {
    key: df.assign(Sum=df[columnlist].sum(axis=1)) for key, df in df_dict.items()
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this earlier but didn't have success:

`df_sum_dict = { k: v['Sum'] = v[columnlist].sum(axis=1) for k,v in df_dict.items()}`

receiving a syntax error at the equals sign, curious what i'm missing.

Comment: @rweber `v['Sum'] = ...` is an _assignment_, not an object (it has no value), whereas `df.assign(...)` returns a dataframe, which is an object. So, trying to put this non-object into a dictionary is sort of a category error.